Yii2 tests not flush db changes on disk. How to disable it?
I got simple ActiveRecord model (CRUD from Gii) and unit tests for that, with one simple adding test.
In the test i just fill model fields and call $model->save(). After that, test check tables row count. Here all good, works fine.
$ip = new Ip();
$ip->ip = '1.1.1.1';
$ip->save();

verify(Ip::find()->count())->equals(1);
verify(Ip::find()->where(['ip'=>'1.1.1.1'])->one())->notEmpty();

But if i look in the test db table after test is done (by mysql client or pma), i see a 0 rows there.
If i put sleep(60) in the tests code, and go to PMA when sleep is going - i see 0 rows there. But yii2+codecept see this row, extract from db, verify values.
I think tests works in the one big transaction and not flushing on disk. How can i disable it?

I think transaction part of config is what you are looking for. But I don't recommend turning it off for unit tests. Unit tests should run in well-known constant environment to make sure the conditions are always same. If you need to have some data available in DB for tests you should use fixtures instead of creating data in other tests.
